# I cannot select span:before with CSS

Tags: html, css

I want to access span elements inside .payment-method. For first span element I want to set image "image1.png" and for second element "image2.png".

Here is my HTML code:

```css
.payment-group .payment-method:nth-child(0){
  .payment-method-title label span:before{
    content: url(https://icon-library.com/images/delivery-service-icon/delivery-service-icon-6.jpg);
  }
} 
.payment-group.payment-method:nth-child(1){
  .payment-method-title label span:before{
    content: url(https://icon-library.com/images/bank-transfer-icon/bank-transfer-icon-6.jpg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="payment-group">
  <div class="payment-method">
    <div class="payment-method-title field choice">
      <input type="radio" class="radio" id="cashondelivery" value="cashondelivery"/>
      <label class="label">
        <span>Cash on delivery</span>
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="payment-method">
    <div class="payment-method-title field choice">
      <input type="radio" class="radio" id="banktransfer" value="banktransfer"/>
      <label class="label">
        <span>Bank transfer</span>
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Can someone help me ?
(I am using LESS, but you can help me with plain CSS)

Comment: `:nth-child(0)` does not exist

Comment: Also this does not look right `.payment-group.payment-method:nth-child(1)` did you mean  `.payment-group .payment-method:nth-child(1)`

Comment: Then how can I do that ? @Paulie_D (I tried to place there whitespace, no effect)

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems here:

nth-child starts at 1 not 0 in CSS.

The nesting of selectors does not exist in pure CSS, this snippet 'flattens' them

Space is a very important character in a CSS selector. It is a 'combinator'. The second selector missed it out before .payment-method

the before of a pseudo element nowadays should have a double colon as in ::before (this indicates a pseudo element as opposed to a pseudo class).

```css
.payment-group .payment-method:nth-child(1) .payment-method-title label span::before {
  content: url(https://icon-library.com/images/delivery-service-icon/delivery-service-icon-6.jpg);
}

.payment-group .payment-method:nth-child(2) .payment-method-title label span::before {
  content: url(https://icon-library.com/images/bank-transfer-icon/bank-transfer-icon-6.jpg);
}
```

```html
<div class="payment-group">
  <div class="payment-method">
    <div class="payment-method-title field choice">
      <input type="radio" class="radio" id="cashondelivery" value="cashondelivery" />
      <label class="label">
        <span>Cash on delivery</span>
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="payment-method">
    <div class="payment-method-title field choice">
      <input type="radio" class="radio" id="banktransfer" value="banktransfer" />
      <label class="label">
        <span>Bank transfer</span>
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```